# android : Getting "null" from intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-studio

- I am developing an application in which i want to capture the image from the camera and display it in another activity in an image view, my problem is that in OnActivityResult I am getting a "null" in data... I don't know why

Here is my Code..
`PictureOptions.java`

```
public void buttonCameraOpen(View view)
{
    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
      return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Easy Heal");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

 // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     Bitmap selectedphoto   = null;

     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE  && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null!=data) {

            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            //selectedphoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
             String [] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
             Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
             cursor.moveToFirst();   
             int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
             String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
             File f =new File(filePath);
             String filename = f.getName();
             cursor.close();
             selectedphoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

             Intent intent = new Intent(PictureOptions.this,ShowImage.class);
             //intent.putExtra("data", selectedphoto);
             intent.setData( selectedImage );
             startActivity(intent);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } else {
            // Image capture failed, advise user
       }

}
```

`PictureOptions.xml`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonCameraOpen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.35"
    android:onClick="buttonCameraOpen"
    android:text="@string/button_camera_open" />
```

`ShowImage.java`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_image);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageShow);
    Uri imageUri = getIntent().getData();
    //Bitmap selectedphoto  =(Bitmap)this.getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
    imageview.setImageURI(imageUri);
}
```

`ShowImage.xml`

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageShow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Please show the code that set the activity result

Comment: You really don't need to access the data object to get the captured image. Instead you can store the generated file path form your getOutputMediaFile method and use it in onActivityResult method to obtain the captured image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well from Capturing image you don't need to store this image in a file. You can get Bitmap directly using following method. This is just you are doing some extra work.

```
//Global variable
private static final int TAKE_IMAGE = 2;


//OnClick of your button or whereever you want to start camera
   @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_IMAGE); 
       }

//onActivityREsul portion of your code
```

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

```
    if(requestCode == TAKE_IMAGE ){
        try {

                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           // bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap( getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),  capturedImageUri);


            YourImageViewObject.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            } 


    }


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: then how will I send it to another activity

Comment: You Should make a static Bitmap in a class like this.
make a new class named Constats
declare this static variable like this 
public static Bitmap mySharedBitmap;

onActivityResult di this.
Constants.mySharedBitmap=bitmap;
and in other activity get it by
Constatns.mySharedBitmap
Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> This happened because you forgot to add Write External storage
>   permission  Or the folder you trying to save image doest not exist ,
>   please create folder first.

Please Add  `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

try to save another location

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"Easy Heal");
```

Comment: Could yo please Log the output of getOutputMediaFile? is this correct? I am sure you are not getting valid path , please check and update

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ravir, PID: 22960
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=null} to activity java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Use this code also in your activity if not added

```
@Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");

        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Comment: Why i should have to write this?

Comment: It is saving your activtiy state when your camera opens and when camera closes it restores the fileuri. Just give a try.